# Spring boot MockMvc post not enter to real conntroller method

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc

I have controllers method

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getTransaction/{transactionUuid}")
  public ResponseEntity<TransactionDetail> getTransaction(@PathVariable() String transactionUuid) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(transactionsService.getOpcTransaction(transactionUuid));
  }
```

I write test for controller:

```
@Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/nfp-server/getTransaction/{transactionUuid}", "123"))
      .andDo(print());
  }
```

I star test in debug mode - but I not enter to controller `getTransaction` method. And in log I see:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /server/getTransaction/123
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}
```

Comment: what is this `nfp-server`? Do you have this mapping defined at class level ? How are you initializing mockMvc in your test?

Comment: what is this nfp-server? Do you have this mapping defined at class level  - yes. I removed this and all work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller your mapping is

```
/getTransaction/{transactionUuid}
```

In your test class you are passing

```
 /nfp-server/getTransaction/{transactionUuid}
```

There is a mismatch.